# "#{..} is not allowed in template text" after jsp file splitting

Tags: jsp, jsf

I'm using a

```
<s:radio  list="#{'used': 'Mark as used', 'available': 'Mark as available'}" name="selections" value="%{'used'}"></s:radio>
```

tag inside a index.jsp page and it works properly.

If I'm including the same code in another .jsp page that is included afterwards into the initial index.jsp file, I'm getting the following error:

```
17:01:25,564 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /voucher.jsp(20,26) #{..} is not allowed in template text
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:711)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:935)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2338)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2388)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2394)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:489)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2338)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1737)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:178)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:306)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:557)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:481)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
17:01:25,565 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /voucher.jsp(20,26) #{..} is not allowed in template text
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:711)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:935)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2338)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2388)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2394)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:489)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2338)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1737)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:178)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:306)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:557)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:481)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [#{...} is not allowed in template text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478640/is-not-allowed-in-template-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `<s:xxx>` taglib in top of the JSP. Otherwise the `<s:radio>` won't be recognized as a fullworthy tag and just be interpreted as template text.

#### See also:

- [#{...} is not allowed in template text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478640/is-not-allowed-in-template-text)