# JSF 2.0 WITH richfaces 4.2.3 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Web/login.jsp(21,20) #{...} is not allowed in template text

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I am currently working on a project that I would like to migrate over to RichFaces 4.2.3 from version 3.3.3. and  JSF1.2 into JSF2.0 . 
After deploying my project getting some strange kind of error. 
**"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Web/login.jsp(21,20) #{...} is not allowed in template text"** 
Here is my login.jsp file

```
<code>


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Registration is successful.</h1>
    <a4j:commandButton value="LOGIN"  
        action="#{userBean.validateUser}" />
</body>
</html>
<code>
```

More strange point this error is occured only with  **action tag**  
action="#{userBean.validateUser}"  and work with value="#{userBean.pwd}" 
 
Guys please try to help me out from here, i already waste my whole day with this issue. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like richfaces 4 and onwards does not support JSPs

[#{...} is not allowed in template text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478640/is-not-allowed-in-template-text)

Comment: RF 4 does not support JSP at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, is there way to do this ???

Comment: Just stop using JSPs. See also the duplicate question link.

Comment: Do what BalusC said ;P

Answer (score 1):

JSP is [**deprecated**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) since JSF 2.0. All component libraries which are designed for JSF 2.0 from ground on won't support JSP anymore. This includes among others RichFaces 4.x. RichFaces 3.x is a JSF 1.x compatible component library which can also be used on JSF 2.0. As it's originally JSF 1.x compatible, it just supports JSP.

If you need to migrate to RichFaces 4.x, you should also migrate from JSP to Facelets (XHTML).

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870)