# Migrating a war running on tomcat to JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jboss

In few jsp pages, I am getting below exception on jboss, while it was working fine on tomcat.
     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /xxx.jsp(210,9) #{..} is not allowed in template text

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i guess, someone else also asked this question in the past 
[#{...} is not allowed in template text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478640/is-not-allowed-in-template-text)
See if it helps..

Comment: It's given, an alternative is to use the older RichFaces 3.x version instead. Version 3.3.3 supports JSF 2.0 on JSP. It offers the <a4j:support> tag to achieve the same. i didn't get, where and which jar to replace in jboss to get things working?