# How to display css style in HTML div?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I want to show style full CSS from my database.

`#{Customization.headerCss}` has value `style="display:none;"`.

I want to show my `<div>` on the basis of `#{Customization.headerCss}` value , it will be none or block.

My code is like :

```
<div class="_content-title _radius-5px _ie8";"  #{Customization.headerCss} >
     <p>Hello display is block </p>
 </div>
```

I am getting error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /cardMgmt/preview/preview.jsp(700,68) #{..} is not allowed in template text
```

What should I have to do?

Comment: [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548556/is-not-allowed-in-template-text-in-spring-web-application)   [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478640/is-not-allowed-in-template-text)

Comment: @lukaslew what should I have to do to make this thing work?

Comment: Have you tried change `#{...}` to `${...}` (first link)?

Comment: @lukaslew Thanks It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

I got solution of it : $ in place of #

```
<div class="_content-title _radius-5px _ie8";"  ${Customization.headerCss} >
    <p>Hello display is block </p>
 </div>
```